# Laravel 8 CRUD: "POST" Method not Working Despite Proper Routing and HTML Configuration

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, crud

When I submit my user form, nothing happens:
I don't understand why nothing is happening. If I change the "POST" method to "PUT", it only redirects me to the index page. Please help. Thank you.
CRUD Route:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\PostsController;
Route::resource('posts', PostsController::class);
```

Store function within PostsController:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'Product1' => 'required',
    ]);

    $post = new Posts();
    $post->Product1= $request->Product1;
    $post->save();
    
    return redirect()->route('posts.index')->with('success', 'Post created successfully');
    
}
```

HTML form:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('posts.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf   
    <table class="table" style="border-style: none;">
        <tr>
            <th>{{ __('Product1:') }}</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="Product1" class="form-control"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: did you check in the browser source if the generated form action is generated correctly?

Comment: How? Do you mean in the browser console? nothing is happening.

Answer (score 1):

### Welcome to SO

**your code is wrong**

```html
<input type="text" name="title" class="form-control">
```

here `name` attribute is important it create a key which then get in backend for this code `$request->title` you will get in you controller

but your code should be like this

```html
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('posts.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf   
    <table class="table" style="border-style: none;">
        <tr>
            <th>{{ __('Product1:') }}</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="product" class="form-control"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

#### in controller

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'product' => 'required',
    ]);

    $post = new Posts();
    $post->Product1= $request->product; // it should be match with input name
    $post->save();
    
    return redirect()->route('posts.index')->with('success', 'Post created successfully');
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've changed the name attributes, but my problem is with the POST method. When I click submit, nothing happens.